# How to assert a sequence of member calls without caring for arguments with unittest.mock?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am looking to assert a sequence of calls, without caring for what arguments are given.  Is there any way to accomplish the following?

```
self.mocker = Mock()
self.mocker.increment = Mock()
self.mocker.decrement = Mock()

self.mocker.increment(2)
self.mocker.decrement(4)

expected_calls = [call.increment(ANY_ARGS), call.decrement(ANY_ARGS)]

self.mocker.assert_has_calls(expected_calls, any_order=False)
```

Comment: You don't need to assign more morks to `increment` and `decrement`; those are automatically mocks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to look at the [`mock_calls` list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) and extract the names for each call recorded. You can then assert that the right method names are called, in order:

```
self.assertEqual([c[0] for c in self.mocker.mock_calls], ['increment', 'decrement'])
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> mocker = mock.Mock()
>>> mocker.increment(2)
<Mock name='mock.increment()' id='4546399144'>
>>> mocker.decrement(4)
<Mock name='mock.decrement()' id='4546398752'>
>>> mocker.mock_calls
[call.increment(2), call.decrement(4)]
>>> mocker.mock_calls[0][0]
'increment'
>>> [c[0] for c in mocker.mock_calls]
['increment', 'decrement']
```